# django user profile setup with image upload

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I got interested in django few days ago and I'm trying to build a little social network for practicing. But am encountering an issue on file uploading for user profile. Please find below the details :

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('photos', str(instance.id), filename)

class Userprofile(models.Model) :
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True)

User.profile = property(lambda x : Userprofile.objects.get_or_create(user=x)[0])
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from models import Userprofile

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm) :

    class Meta :
        model = Userprofile
```

views.py

```
def profilewizard(request) :

    if request.method == 'POST' :    
        print request.POST
        print request.FILES
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=request.user.profile)

        if form.is_valid() :
            form.save()

    form = UserProfileForm()
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['current_user'] = request.user
    args['form'] = form

    return render_to_response('profilewizard.html',args)
```

I notice that an empty row is added into the database and I have an error displayed in my console

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 46869)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 129, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 279, in close
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I do not understatnd why nothing is stored in the database althought the form is valid

Thx for the help

Cheers,
Mouha

Comment: Here's a good resource to check out for a simple implementation on how to create a form with a file image upload --> http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/login.html#the-user-model

Comment: thx it helped a lot my pb was the blank=True I removed it an it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is a django know bug that will not be fixed but the upload works